# Adding multiple Audio Hlsmedia source using Dynamicmediasource In Exoplayer without pause currently playing Player.

Tags: android, audio, exoplayer

I want to make Dynamic Audio Playlist using Exoplayer.I used DynamicMediaSource as well as ConcateMediaSource it will work fine but if my player is currently playing and i will try to add mediasource then current player can be go on pause state and newly added mediasource will be playing.Initially i will create media source for only one audio and make player.playWhenReady true for only first time.then add another source in list and create audio source for my playlist.
So is it possible to add mediasouce without pause player? And playlist can be play in added manner? 
below code is for create media souce for first audio:-

```
fun createAudioSource(data: MusicDetailResponse.AudioX, audioAllItem: MusicDetailResponse.Audio, position: Int) {

    player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(context, DefaultTrackSelector())
    val userAgent = Util.getUserAgent(context, context.getString(R.string.label_user_agent))
    val dataSourceFactory = DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory(
            userAgent, null,
            DefaultHttpDataSource.DEFAULT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS,
            1800000,
            true)

    val hlsMediaSource = HlsMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
                .createMediaSource(Uri.parse(data.audio))
    player!!.prepare(hlsMediaSource)
    player!!.playWhenReady = true

}
fun addAudioList(item: MusicDetailResponse.AudioX) {
   tempAudioList.add(item)
   createHlsMediaSource(tempAudioList)
}

private fun createHlsMediaSource(tempAudioList: ArrayList<MusicDetailResponse.AudioX>) {
   for (i in 1 until tempAudioList.size) {
        val userAgent = Util.getUserAgent(context, context.getString(R.string.label_user_agent))
        val dataSourceFactory = DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory(
                userAgent, null,
                DefaultHttpDataSource.DEFAULT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS,
                1800000,
                true)
        val hlsMediaSource = HlsMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
                .createMediaSource(Uri.parse(tempAudioList[i].audio))
        cMediaSource!!.addMediaSource(hlsMediaSource)
    }

    player?.prepare(cMediaSource, false, false)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Renamed all occurrences of DynamicConcatenatingMediaSource to ConcatenatingMediaSource.

Ever wanted to support media playlists in your Android app, where users can add and remove playlist items arbitrarily during playback? Now you can!

From ExoPlayer 2.8.0 onward we’ve updated the ConcatenatingMediaSource with dynamic playlist functionality. On the surface the new media source has a very simple and straightforward interface:

addMediaSource(mediaSource) appends a new media source at the end of the playlist.
addMediaSource(index, mediaSource) inserts a new media source at the specified index in the playlist.
addMediaSources(Collection) bulk appends a whole set of new media sources at the end of the playlist.
addMediaSources(index, Collection) bulk inserts a set of new media sources at the specified index in the playlist.
removeMediaSource(index) removes the media source at the given index.
moveMediaSource(fromIndex, toIndex) moves an existing media source within the playlist. This is useful as you do not have to create a new MediaSource object. And you can also move around the currently playing item without disrupting playback.
getMediaSource(index) allows you to access the media source at the given index.
getSize() returns the current playlist length.

Comment: I'm trying to move media sources around, but the playing index is not being updated. If I move the playing MediaSource from position 5 to position 1, for example, the next position to be played will still be 6, instead of 2. Do you know how I can change this?